# BLAS subroutines dgemm, dgemv and ddot doesn't work with scalars?

Tags: matrix, fortran, gfortran, scalar

I have a Fortran subroutine which uses BLAS' subroutines dgemm, dgemv and ddot, which calculate matrix * matrix, matrix * vector and vector * vector. I have m * m matrices and m * 1 vectors. In some cases m=1. It seems that those subroutines doesn't work well in those cases. They doesn't give errors, but there seems to be some numerical unstability in results. So I have to write something like:

```
if(m>1) then 
  vtuni(i,t) = yt(i,t) - ct(i,t) - ddot(m, zt(i,1:m,(t-1)*tvar(3)+1), 1, arec, 1)
else 
   vtuni(i,t) = yt(i,t) - ct(i,t) - zt(i,1,(t-1)*tvar(3)+1)*arec(1)
```

So my actual question is, am I right that those BLAS' subroutines doesn't work properly when m=1 or is there just something wrong in my code? Can the compiler affect this? I'm using gfortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLAS routines are supposed to behave correctly with objects of size 1. I don't think it can depend on compiler, but it could possible depend on the implementation of BLAS you're relying on (though I'd consider it a bug of the implementation). The reference (read: not target-optimised) implementation of BLAS, which can be found on [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/blas/ddot.f), handles that case fine.

I've done some testing on both arrays of size 1, and size-1 slices of larger array (as in your own code), and they both work fine:

> ```
>  $ cat a.f90 
>  implicit none
>  double precision :: u(1), v(1)
>  double precision, external :: ddot
>  u(:) = 2
>  v(:) = 3
>  print *, ddot(1, u, 1, v, 1)
>  end
>  $ gfortran a.f90 -lblas && ./a.out
>   6.0000000000000000     
>
>  $ cat b.f90                       
>  implicit none
>  double precision, allocatable :: u(:,:,:), v(:)
>  double precision, external :: ddot
>  integer :: i, j
>  allocate(u(3,1,3),v(1))
>  u(:,:,:) = 2
>  v(:) = 3
>  i = 2
>  j = 2
>  print *, ddot(1, u(i,1:1,j), 1, v, 1)
>  end
>  $ gfortran b.f90 -lblas && ./a.out
>   6.0000000000000000
> ```

Things I'd consider to debug this problem further:

- Check that your `ddot` definition is correct
- Substitute the reference BLAS to your optimised one, to check if it changes anything (you can just compile and link in the `ddot.f` file I linked to earlier in my answer)